# Woocommerce get product count by id (in cart)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to get the number of items of a specific product by its id? For example, I added to my cart 5 green apples and 10 lemons. I want to get the number of green apples in cart (which is 5), by the id of the green apple product.

Is there a simple way to achieve? Thanks

Comment: Where in the cart you want to display this ?

Comment: I just need to get it as a variable

Answer (score 2):

Ok I cracked it:

```
$cartId = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( PRODUCT_ID);
$cartItemKey = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cartId );
$startingVal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents()[$cartItemKey]["quantity"];
```

Comment: Ok. Glad that you got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to get product quantity of a particular product

```
$quantity = '';
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if( $cart_item['product_id'] == 'your_id_here'){
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
}
```